# Google Script: Using an input text box in a form that pulls items from the sheet and presents as options

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently developing a program in Google Script that works with Google Sheets. I've created a tab that serves as the UI and have multiple tabs for each data type to store the data.

When I first started, I originally reserved some cells on the UI tab that I used as the inputs for creating a parent-child relationship instance. To do this, I directly set validation on each of the cells and used the "List from a range" Criteria to provide the drop-down list to provide the options to select from.

Now, I am trying to move this input off of the cells in the UI tab and into the sidebar. I am now using HTML Service and am creating a form to handle this functionality. However, I can't figure out where to get started to provide the same drop-down functionality for each of the text inputs in the form as I had when I used the cell validation.

Does anyone know what syntax is used to do this?

Thank you,
Nicholas Kincaid

Comment: I forgot to include that I am fine with grabbing that data from the tables in the form of an array in JavaScript. I am just having trouble with taking that data and presenting it in the text box.

Comment: a text box with a dropdown (combobox) or just a dropdown?

Comment: Thank you, Bryan. I started with your question and eventually got to what I was looking for. It looks as though the jQuery Autocomplete combo-box is what will take care of this => https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

Comment: just mark as answered too

Comment: Thanks, looks like SO won't let us check our own answer until 17 hours passes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery auto-complete combo-box is what will take care of this => jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html